# Why does adding .js make Rails render 10x faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

Rails apps often use AJAX to render dynamic javascript views. E.g. `update.js.erb`. The contents of the view is simple jQuery to swap page elements with partials rendered inline.

The issue is partials rendered seem to take 10x longer than they should when requested via js. When used elsewhere in the app in HTML format they render as fast as expected.

While testing with curl I finally found what "causes" the slowdown. Or rather, adding ".js" to the end of the URL fixes the slowdown - the partials render in JS format just as fast as they do in HTML format. Why? Either way the request and response is the same; Rails is rendering the JS. It's only the .js in the URL that makes a mysterious difference.

The `Accept: text/javascript` header makes no difference, nor do any other headers browsers send. Why would not having .js on a Javascript request make it so much slower? Doesn't .js URL / Accept header do the same thing; tell Rails the format. Why would Rails be doing something different and what?

We use URL generators which don't generate the .js and I don't want to manually add `format: :js` to all of them. I've been banging my head for days so any help would be really appreciated!

I made a minimal reproduction, no DB queries just simple views: https://github.com/sfcgeorge/url-format-speed

Relevant part of logs:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000/test_nested' -H 'Accept: */*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript'

Started GET "/test_nested" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-01 16:38:23 +0100
Processing by TestsController#test_nested as JS
  Rendering tests/test_nested.js.erb
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered tests/test_nested.js.erb (129.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 160ms (Views: 145.3ms)
```

^ see how slow that is?

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000/test_nested.js' -H 'Accept: */*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript'

Started GET "/test_nested.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-01 16:39:11 +0100
Processing by TestsController#test_nested as JS
  Rendering tests/test_nested.js.erb
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered tests/_partial.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered tests/test_nested.js.erb (17.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 22.0ms)
```

I opened an issue with Rails because after finding a minimal reproduction I suspect it's a bug. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30502

Comment: my guess is that rails calculates which template to render when there is no extension - it looks up all of the possible options, but if you provide the extension then it doe not do that lookup

Comment: Add logs as text to question body - screenshots or linked code contributes to link rot and are not acceptable on stackoverflow.

Comment: mgidea - Maybe. But shouldn't it do it just once for the show template, not every single partial? It's adding up to over a second of nothing. And if that is the case, why is Rails ignoring the Accept header, I thought they did the same thing?